# What is the difference between 山顶and 山巅?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two words?  Is there any difference? Are they used in different regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are both peak.

For me, 山顶 is more general word for peak. But 山巅 is more powerful, usually is used in  the literature.

You can say 山顶 for a hill or a mountain, but you don't know if there are other higher 山顶s around. But 山巅 is supposed to be the highest among the nearby region.